# IPP AppCenter disconnect doesn't redirect to "disconnect landing page"

Tags: oauth, intuit-partner-platform

According to the Intuit docs

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0030_integrate_your_app/disconnecting_from_quickbooks/0020_disconnecting_intuit_app_center_(implement_the_disconnect_landing_page)

and the tech review checklist

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0040_publishing_your_app/0010_reviewing_the_requirements_checklist

when I disconnect from the app center is should be redirecting or directing to the "Disconnect Landing Page" I've specified in my "Manage Application > App Details" configuration. However, when I test this process, it just confirms "Yes, I want to disconnect, revokes the OAuth token and shows an "OK" button which closes the dialog. My logs don't show any requests of anykind to my server.

Any idea why it's not redirecting or showing the "Next" button?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the customer clicks on the Disconnect link for your application in the Manage My Apps section of the App Center we redirect the browser to the URL entered in the Disconnect URL section for your application. It is important that you provide the correct URLs for both the development and production environment.

There is currently a bug in the development application environment where the redirect does not happen automatically. To simulate the proper flow you can simply paste the Disconnect URL into the browser after the App Center completes the disconnect process. We use this method to complete the testing during the technical review .

Comment: Excellent. That method has been working in development. I guess I'll send it in for technical review, and assume production will work. Thanks.