# Diconnected from App Center through my application using java SDK

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I face an issue while running disconnect from app center via my application. here is my source code.

```
private boolean disconnet(final String oauthConsumerKey, final String oauthConsumerSecret, final String accessToken, final String accessTokenSecret, final String realmID) {
 try {
           if (accessToken != null && accessTokenSecret != null
                           && realmID != null) {
                   final IAPlatformClient pClient = new IAPlatformClient();
                   pClient.disconnect(oauthConsumerKey, oauthConsumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
                   return true;
           }
   } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Exception : "+e.getMessage());
           return false;
   }
 return false;
}
```

I get the exception:

```
Exception :Failed to disconnect: java.lang.NullPointerException null
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We currently have a defect in the development environment that prevents the disconnect from the app center flow to be executed properly. The defect only affects the development environment, the production environment is working correctly.

The defect presents a pop up with a Close button at the end of the sequence and control is returned to the app center Manage My Apps page rather than directing the user to the application's disconnect URL.

To test this after returning to the app center, simply paste the disconnect URL into the browser address box and manually navigate to the disconnect URL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please just to confirm something. the disconnect i'm trying to implement is the one from my application. I saw a post ["here"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459128/ipp-appcenter-disconnect-doesnt-redirect-to-disconnect-landing-page/17463009#17463009) about issue of url redirection in case of a disconnection from quickbooks. Disconnect Landing URL is used for disconnection through quickbooks. right? this Url is it used for disconnection implemented in my application(code in my first post)? I think it's a different flow. please correct me if i'm wrong. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you are talking about the same thing. This issue happens with apps who disconnect from app center in dev mode