# Quickbooks + rails 3: Disconnect app from intuit app center

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

If I am disconnecting connected intuit app from my rails application,It is working fine and doing following things:

- Disconnecting app from My app and displyaing connect to quickbooks button
- Disconnecting app from app center and It is no longer displaying in appcenter

**Problem**

Now, if user disconnect app from intuit app center i.e https://appcenter.intuit.com/Home/ManageSubscriptions/ "disconnect from quickbooks" button is still displaying in my rails app.

I have configured disconnect landing url in developer.intuit.com also:

Disconnect Landing URL: [http://demoapp/settings/dis_quickbooks url](http://myurl.com/settings/dis_quickbooks)

I have copy and pasted [http://demoapp/settings/dis_quickbooks url](http://myurl.com/settings/dis_quickbooks%20url) in my browser and it is disconnecting my connected app. But the problem exists when user disconnect from appcenter.

I think with Disconnect Landing URL it should work automatically when user disconnect their app from appcenter?

## edit:

**[NOTE: I have hosted my site in `heroku`]**

Answer (score 1):

Please refer my post on this link -

[IPP AppCenter disconnect doesn't redirect to "disconnect landing page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459128/ipp-appcenter-disconnect-doesnt-redirect-to-disconnect-landing-page)

In production(publised app), this feature will work in the expected way.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but It is not even working for production environment too... and my rails app didn't pass intuit review process because of this behaviour. I think it should work for my production environment right? I am not testing it in development environment. any more suggestions please.

Comment: did you raise any support ticket for this ? If so, can you please reply to that one ? otherwise please raise one ticket from https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support

Comment: Hi Manas, how to raise a ticket?? And also, I forget to say that, My site is hosted in ```heroku``` is it making any problem?

Comment: I've mentioned the support link in my previous post. It is - https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incidents. Deployment environment should not cause any issue.